# How to print paths in DFS manner in graphs?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree, stack

I have a tree(not binary tree) in which I would like to get paths from the root node to all leaves. 
For instance;

```
    A
  / | \ 
 B  C  D
/ \ | / \
E F G H I
```

I want to get all the paths = {[A,B,E], [A,B, F], [A, C, G], [A, D, H], 
[A, D, I]}

What I have done up to now is;

I have a Graph class;

```
public class Graph {
    static class Node{
       String name;
       HashSet<Edge> inEdges;
       HashSet<Edge> outEdges;}
    static class Edge{
       Node from;
       Node to;
       String id;} 
}
```

And I traverse the tree with this snippet;

```
void printAllPaths(rootNode, list) {
    System.out.println(rootNode.name);
    list.add(rootNode.name);
    int childCount = rootNode.outEdges.size();
    if (childCount == 0) {
        System.out.println(list);
        list.pop();//one for node
        list.pop();//one for edge
    } else {
        for (Graph.Edge e : rootNode.outEdges) {
            System.out.println(e.id);
            list.add(e.id);
            printAllPaths(e.to, list, rootNodeReplica);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am basically doing is;

- add Node and Edge to the stack
- if the node has children, do the same as above
- if the node is a leaf, print the list/stack and pop the node from the list/stack

However;
When the algorithm finishes B Node branch and move to C; the list still keeps {A Edge B}, However when changing branch it should just include Node A. So that my path becomes ; **A Edge B Edge C Edge G** not **A edge C edge G**.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance
Kind Regards

Comment: You've got it almost right, except that when to remove a node from the list. When you're leaving a node (that is you've traversed the node and all of it's successors), you don't want it to show up anymore in any path.

Comment: Thank you @halfo.  However I couldn't quite get it. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler version of the problem. Say, we're given given a chain `A -- B -- E`. We've to print the following triangular shape.

```
A
A B
A B C
A B C
A B
A
```

Can we do it using recursion? Sure we can!

```
void printEachPath(currentRoot, stack) {
    if (currentRoot == null) return;

    stack.push(currentRoot.name);
    print stack;

    printEachPath(currentRoot->next, stack);

    print stack; 
    stack.pop(currentRoot.name);
}
```

I hope you've got some hints from this.